# Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 Image Zoom

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I have windows phone silverlight 8.1 app. I want to zoom the image. Here is my code snippet. The issue is that it does not zoom on the place where pinch is performed. It always zoom in at top left corner of the image. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
private void Image_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PinchManipulation != null)
    {
        var transform = (CompositeTransform)img.RenderTransform;

        // Scale Manipulation
        transform.ScaleX = e.PinchManipulation.CumulativeScale;
        transform.ScaleY = e.PinchManipulation.CumulativeScale;

        // Translate manipulation
        var originalCenter = e.PinchManipulation.Original.Center;
        var newCenter = e.PinchManipulation.Current.Center;
        transform.TranslateX = newCenter.X - originalCenter.X;
        transform.TranslateY = newCenter.Y - originalCenter.Y;

        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is to put Image in ScrollViewer in that way System Manipulation will do all zooming thing for free.

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Image />
</ScrollViewer>
```

If it's not answer of your question ,let me know then i'll delete my post.

Comment: This does not work. image view does not zoom doing this. Thats why did not put it inside scroll viewer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `transform.CenterX` and `transform.CenterY`